# Shorten a line by a number of pixels

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, gdi+, drawing

I'm drawing a custom diagram of business objects using .NET GDI+. Among other things, the diagram consists of several lines that are connecting the objects.

In a particular scenario, I need to shorten a line by a specific number of pixels, let's say 10 pixels, i.e. find the point on the line that lies 10 pixels before the end point of the line.

Imagine a circle with radius *r* = 10 pixels, and a line with start point (x1, y1) and end point (x2, y2). The circle is centered at the end point of the line, as in the following illustration.

[image: Illustration]

How do I calculate the point marked with a red circle, i.e. the intersection between circle and line? This would give me the new end point of the line, shortening it by 10 pixels.

---

### Solution

Thank you for your answers from which I was able to put together the following procedure. I named it LengthenLine, since I find it more natural to pass a negative number of pixels if I want the line shortened.

Specifically, I was trying to put together a function that could draw a line with rounded corners, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805582/net-gdi-drawing-lines-with-rounded-corners).

```
public void LengthenLine(PointF startPoint, ref PointF endPoint, float pixelCount)
{
  if (startPoint.Equals(endPoint))
    return; // not a line

  double dx = endPoint.X - startPoint.X;
  double dy = endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y;
  if (dx == 0)
  {
    // vertical line:
    if (endPoint.Y < startPoint.Y)
      endPoint.Y -= pixelCount;
    else
      endPoint.Y += pixelCount;
  }
  else if (dy == 0)
  {
    // horizontal line:
    if (endPoint.X < startPoint.X)
      endPoint.X -= pixelCount;
    else
      endPoint.X += pixelCount;
  }
  else
  {
    // non-horizontal, non-vertical line:
    double length = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    double scale = (length + pixelCount) / length;
    dx *= scale;
    dy *= scale;
    endPoint.X = startPoint.X + Convert.ToSingle(dx);
    endPoint.Y = startPoint.Y + Convert.ToSingle(dy);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you're trying to shorten a finite line. Cause I don't know *how* the heck I'd go about shortening an infinite one :-)

Comment: Haha, d'oh. A result of rephrasing the title several times. I'll change it once more :)

Comment: I think the term you were looking for is 'line segment' =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Find the direction vector, i.e. let the position vectors be (using floats) B = (x2, y2) and A = (x1, y1), then AB = B - A. Normalize that vector by dividing by its length ( Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y) ). Then multiply the direction vector AB by the original length minus the circle's radius, and add back to the lines starting position:

```
double dx = x2 - x1;
double dy = y2 - y1;
double length = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
if (length > 0)
{
    dx /= length;
    dy /= length;
}
dx *= length - radius;
dy *= length - radius;
int x3 = (int)(x1 + dx);
int y3 = (int)(y1 + dy);
```

Edit: Fixed the code, aaand fixed the initial explanation (thought you wanted the line to go out from the circle's center to its perimeter :P)

Comment: You even be able to "optimize" (not as in micro-optimization) it a little, by precalculating the multiplication factor `double scale = (length - radius) / length`, but I tend to think in stepwise vector operations.

Comment: Length is only 0 when **both dx and dy equal zero**, so you should check `if (dx == 0 && dy == 0)` before the expensive square root. And what happens if length is zero? Why do you still multiply the length when it's zero

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You can use similar triangles. For the main triangle, `d` is the hypotenuses and the extension of `r` is the vertical line that meets the right angle. Inside the circle you will have a smaller triangle with a hypotenuses of length `r`.

```
r/d = (x2-a0)/(x2-x1) = (y2-b0)/(y2-y1)

a0 = x2 + (x2-x1)r/d

b0 = y2 + (y2-y1)r/d
```

Comment: @unholysampler: I've contributed my handdrawn pic. If you don't like it, just rollback :-)

Comment: Keep in mind you'll have to watch out for cases where the slope is infinite or zero (i.e., vertical and horizontal lines) or close enough to that to cause overflow - in those cases, your divisions will fail.

Comment: unfortunately the image has been dead

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you even had to introduce the circle. For a line stretching from `(x2,y2)` to `(x1,y1)`, you can calculate any point on that line as:

```
(x2+p*(x1-x2),y2+p*(y1-y2))
```

where `p` is the percentage along the line you wish to go.

To calculate the percentage, you just need:

```
p = r/L
```

So in your case, `(x3,y3)` can be calculated as:

```
(x2+(10/L)*(x1-x2),y2+(10/L)*(y1-y2))
```

For example, if you have the two points `(x2=1,y2=5)` and `(x1=-6,y1=22)`, they have a length of sqrt(7<sup>2</sup> + 17<sup>2</sup> or 18.38477631 and 10 divided by that is 0.543928293. Putting all those figures into the equation above:

```
  (x2 + (10/l)      * (x1-x2) , y2 + (10/l)      * (y1-y2))
= (1  + 0.543928293 * (-6- 1) , 5  + 0.543928293 * (22- 5))
= (1  + 0.543928293 * -7      , 5  + 0.543928293 * 17     )
= (x3=-2.807498053,y3=14.24678098)
```

The distance between `(x3,y3)` and `(x1,y1)` is sqrt(3.192501947<sup>2</sup> + 7.753219015<sup>2</sup>) or 8.384776311, a difference of 10 to within one part in a thousand million, and that's only because of rounding errors on my calculator.

Comment: He "introduced the circle" because he wants to shorten a line by a set amount of pixels (in his case, a radius of a circle) and not by some percentage of the line, i.e. he wants to shave off 10 pixels, not 10%.

Comment: @StianHøiland, the reason I stated you didn't need the circle in the question is because OP already *knew* they wanted 10 pixels removed, the circle is therefore superfluous. And my answer *is* shaving off 10 pixels. The act of dividing 10 by the line length gives you the percentage of `0.544`-ish and *that's* the percentage you use in the equation.